# ember dynamic adapter host update

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an adapter something like this:

```
var Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:4200'
});

if (config.environment === 'production') {
    Adapter.reopen({
       host: 'http://foo.example.com'
    });
}
```

This has been working for a while, but recently something breaks. My ember app interfaces with a number of different subdomains (eg `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`). My understanding is that `reopen` changes all instances, which is what I think happens. When I browse to '/bar' it uses the correct adapter in production, but browsing to '/foo' still uses the `bar.example.com` endpoint.

My question is two fold. Firstly, am I using the right approach here?

Secondly, I'd like to change the adapter based on a runtime setting. I need to work around IE8 lack of CORS support so am thinking that if I have an ie8 switch, the adapter should hit `example.com/foo` instead of `foo.example.com`. In my mind these two areas are conceptually related, but I'm happy to be wrong.

**update**

To simplify things, I essentially want to find the hostname of the request and pass that into the adapter. For example if I browse to `www.example.com` I want the adapter to go fetch a record from `www.example.com/foo`, or when browsing to `www.example2.com` I want the adapter to fetch the record from `www.example2.com/foo`. I hope that makes sense. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but my guess is that the value is being cached. My recommendation is to make `host` a volatile computed property. This actually works out better for you, since that will allow you to better select the host based on runtime configuration. Try something like this:

```
var Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: function() {
        if (config.environment === 'production') {
            return 'http://foo.example.com';
        } else {
            return 'http://localhost:4200';
        }
    }.property().volatile()
});
```

Because Ember-Data always uses Ember's `get` method to fetch properties, changing `host` from a normal property to a computed one should make no difference. And because of that, you're able to select the host at runtime, and make sure that it's computed every time. (Don't worry about the performance of not caching that value, I promise it won't make a noticeable difference.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had tried something similar without volatile(), but ran into trouble at some stage.

Comment: Can you explain this a little more? i.e. within the production if statement how would you dynamically get the current subdomain the user is using? e.g. the url in the browser is http://bob.example.com so it will `return 'http://bob.testapi.com'`

Comment: For that, you can use `window.location`, whose structure is documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

Comment: Great, thank you. I need to work out how to setup the server to accept sub-domains with EmberJS now.

Comment: what is config? I guess maybe you are using ember cli, if someone knows how to make it in a rails ember project would be grateful!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import ENV from 'ember-arp-roomviewer/config/environment';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'arp/v1',
    //host: 'http://localhost/arp/index.php/wp-json',
    //host: 'http://www.acme.net/myroomplan/wp-json',
    host: function() {
        if (ENV.environment === 'production') {
            return 'http://www.acme.net/myroomplan/wp-json';
        } else {
            return 'http://localhost/arp/index.php/wp-json';
        }
    }.property().volatile(),

    headers: {
    'Content-type': 'text/plain' // Stops OPTION headers being sent PITA
  }
```